# Unable to choose desired timestamp-format when loading csv file into table in IBM DB2

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud

I am loading a CSV file into a new table on IBM DB2. The load interface warns me about the timestamp not matching with the data. In the first picture i show what timestamp i need to properly load the data. My problem is that this alternative does not appear in my dropdown selection, shown in the second picture.

Has anyone else experienced this?
Based on what can be perceived from the second picture, is there something obviously that i need to adjust to make the right alternative appear? Or, had the alternative been removed altogether?
All help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

[image: Timestamp alternative needed]
[image: MyTimestamp dropdown]

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. Take a tour and get your first badge-https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Doesn't the instruction shown in your first picture tell you to _enter_ your custom format if you're not satisfied with the predefined choices?

Answer (score 0):

Click on the question mark next to the drop-down menu for details on how to specify a custom format. I am not sure why you the standard format is missing in your menu, but you can specify almost any format based on standard parts like MM, DD, YY or YYYY and more.